# Is there a permanent fix for my hardwood floor buckling?

Tags: flooring

I have a hardwood floor that was built on a slab; I fixed the buckle nicely once already, now the buckle is back.  What do I have to do to permanently fix this problem?

Comment: We need waaaaaaaay more information. Solid hardwood or engineered hardwood? Is it glued directly to the slab? Nailed to a plywood subfloor? Installed as a floating floor with foam underlayment? How did you "fix" the buckle before?

Comment: Yeah, more details, please. Pictures may help, too.

Comment: If the flooring was installed on a slab without a good moisture barrier, the only way to *permanently* fix the problem is to pull it up and install in properly. And to control the humidity in the room.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the time there are only two causes for a buckling floor:

1. Moisture
2. No Expansion

To elaborate, if the flooring material is real hardwood vs laminate and you are cleaning it with a mop, then you are using too much water. A Swiffer wet jet is plenty. Another reason for excess water would be from below, such as cracks in the concrete, or a plumbing leak.

As for the expansion, whether engineered or solid Hardwood, there should be about 1/2" expansion around the entire edge of the floor. Usually Quarter Round (wood trims) covers this gap between the wood and the wall. Sometimes the baseboard can cover this gap as well. If the expansion is not there, when the wood expands and contracts due to weather it will press up against the wall and buckle at its weakest point. This could be in the middle of the floor.

Most of the time expansion is the culprit. The fix would be to pull up the trim around the edge and see if there is adequate expansion.

This applies even with floating floors.

Answer (score 2):

The items that [user23197 lists](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/44198) are correct to a point. The primary villain causing floors to buckle are temperature extremes and changing humidity.  The expansion space around the perimeter of a floating floor is important to give the wood room to expand and contract. Actually, a good engineered hardwood floor is extremely stable under stressful conditions. Most of the time, fluctuating  humidity is the culprit and can be controlled by using a dehumidifier in a damp location.